# Test Coverage on NgRX store selector Unit test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

My test is passing but I am unable to achieve test coverage on a NgRX store select. this.isNIAddress$ is set in ngOnInit.

[image]

I am using Jest and setting the return value of this.isNIAddress$ within the test. If I do not do that then I get an error saying addresses inside the store is empty. How do I mock the getAllValidAddresses selector?

[image]

Error if I add the component.ngOnInit()

[image]

How do I properly test this store observable to obtain code coverage?

Answer (score 0):

As per comments you can have one spy object in your spec:

```
spyOn(component, 'isPostcodeNI').and.returnValue(true);
component.isPostcodeNI(NiAddress[0].postcode);
expect(component.isPostcodeNI).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Now you can expect the spy has been called with the postcode.

Comment: Thank you but: 'NiAddress is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>' the map in the store returns a boolean.

Comment: _map in the store_ which map is it?

Comment: check the updated one

Comment: the rxjs operator map. Inside this.store.select(getAllValidAddresses()).pipe(.....

Comment: Yeah. got it you are passing the postcode to the method in the map't function

Comment: Thank you but again the isNIAddress$ observable is of type boolean.

Comment: Instead you should use the `spy` object and pass the postcode to it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried 'jest.spyOn(store, 'select').mockImplementation(() => of({NiAddress}))' but I still got the same error.